# CSS 3 column layout issues

Tags: html, css

I'm having a few troubles with a 3 column layout I'm currently working on. I can create the layout just fine but there are some niggling issues I need to iron out.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="col1">
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
    </div>
    <div class="col3">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col1
{
  float: left;
}
.col2
{
  float: left;
}
.col3
{
  float: right;
}
.col1,
.col3
{
  width: 100px;
}
```

My first issue is that columns 1 and 3 are fixed width and I need the middle column to expand to fill the gap between the two of them. I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. I can achieve this using absolute positioning but that leads me nicely onto my next problem...

When the browser is resized I need the columns to wrap nicely underneath each other.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated. Ideally I'd like to get this done with as little hacking and javascript as possible.

Here's a fiddle I've started to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/BCJ6C/6/

Cheers!

Comment: Could you use percentage widths? make col1 and col3 10% then col2 80%?
do they absolutely have to align on under another when the screen is re-sized and what would you expect col2 to look like in that case?

Comment: Hi Dave, unfortunately I can't use percentages. See my comment on Salman A's answer for how it should work.

Comment: @Steve Day -How do the yellow boxes work, do they always have fixed height? And what about the content in yellow boxes? does it change?

Comment: No, the fixed height yellow boxes in the fiddle are just for the example sorry. The content is dynamically loaded into all three columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your [fiddle, updated](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/BCJ6C/8/)

Just do not float the middle column. The bad part is that that you have to move it below column 1 and column 3 in the source order. Hope this is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks but column 2 doesn't wrap in your fiddle. I need every column to wrap. When there is not enough room in the browser window for all the columns, ideally, they would wrap one by one. So first, column 3 would wrap leaving two at the top and then as the window gets smaller column2 would then wrap leaving them all in a single line down. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Steve: think I got excited and answered only half of the question. Will update if I could come up with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what youre looking for:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/holy-grail-liquid-layout-no-quirks-mode

Edit: Changed the url. Accidentally posted the older version of this first

Comment: Thanks but I need the columns to wrap when the browser window is resized.

Comment: @Steve Day -What do you mean by wrapping?

Comment: When the browser window is made smaller I need the columns to wrap under each other until they are in a single vertical line. There are fiddles in my original post and the resulting answers with examples that are close to what I need.